# Tools for extracting strings from .vue files for internationalization

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization

I have a Vue.js 2.x web app and I'm looking to internationalize it by extracting all the strings from my .vue files.
My goal is to identify strings that might require translation, even though there might be some strings that don't need to be translated.
Are there any existing tools available for extracting strings from .vue files?

If there aren't any dedicated tools for this purpose, I'm considering implementing my own solution using the [vue-template-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler).

Comment: i plan to do that also with splitting .vue manually to <script> and <template>. then parsing <template> with jsdom and parsing js code to AST (there're literal nodes)

Comment: Asking for libs is offtopic on SO for several reasons. Most things that could be suggested can be found with "vue i18n extract" query on github

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS Code, the i18n Ally plugin works very well:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lokalise.i18n-ally

This plugin can detect hard coded strings, that possibly need translation.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use some Internationalization framework for that. A good example could be [Lingui](https://lingui.dev/) - a JavaScript library for internalization (i18n) of JavaScript projects, including React, Vue, Node.js, etc.

Lingui is an easy yet powerful internationalization framework. They have recently released a [Vue.js Extractor](https://lingui.dev/tutorials/extractor-vue) that provides a custom extractor that handles Vue.js files.

Message extraction is an essential step in the internationalization process. It involves analyzing your code and extracting all messages defined in it so that your message catalogs are always up-to-date with the source code. Visit the [Message Extraction](https://lingui.dev/guides/message-extraction) article to learn how it works in Lingui.

**Example of how your vue file might look when localized with Lingui:**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { i18n } from "@lingui/core"
i18n._("Setup message")
let x: string | number = 1
</script>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
import { i18n } from "@lingui/core"

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      i18n,
      scriptString: i18n.t("Script message"),
    }
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  {{ (x as number).toFixed(2) }}
  {{ i18n.t({ id: "custom.id", message: "My message" }) }}
  {{
    i18n.t({
        message: "My descriptor message",
        id: "my.message",
        comment: "Message comment",
      })
  }}
  {{ i18n._("id used as message") }}
  {{ i18n.t({ id: "My message without ID and context" }) }}
</template>
```